# how to create a task of a specific record type from a workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks

I want to be able to create a task of a specific record type from a workflow. At the moment all I can see is the option for customising certain fields on the task from within the workflow action.

Comment: 1) there is an Idea for this - worth voting on https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br9OAAS and 2) a commenter on the Idea had this interesting workaround: `Spring 14 has a Pilot feature allow you to call a VisualFlow from a workflow. Within the flow you can define your task creation and within that specify what RecordTypeId to use. If you are building in a sandbox create your record types in the main org before you refresh your development sandbox so that the Ids are in synch.`

Answer (score 1):

How about trigger that will set recordType based on some values in new Task?

Comment: not a fan of creating triggers if they are not necessary

Comment: Either trigger or default record type for profile.
Anyway why you need record type on such easy object as task - "Type" picklist is not enought?

Comment: I want to limit the picklist values of certain fields

Comment: Then how about 2 workflows? 1 to create task and second to set record Type on this task after it will be created? I would prefere trigger but it is your call :)

Comment: Workflows don't fire on tasks created by workflows.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas ;/